# Is there a way to detect changes in Memgraph and subsequently trigger an external action?

Tags: memgraphdb

I want to implement a change detection and data syncing with another database (Amazon DynamoDB). The core requirement is to synchronize data to DynamoDB whenever there's a change in Memgraph. I know about Memgraph triggers but they primarily facilitate updating data within Memgraph using Cypher queries. This isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to detect changes in Memgraph and subsequently trigger an external action, such as calling a webhook, sending an AWS SQS message, or invoking an AWS Lambda function? The goal is maintaining data consistency across Memgraph and DynamoDB in my application.